# E: Unable to locate package mysql-community-server

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

in my case i am trying to install mysql 5.7, by following this tutorial https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-mysql-5-7-on-ubuntu-20-04/ , after running this command :

`sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.12-1_all.deb`

In the prompt, they ask me to choose the Ubuntu version ,and by mistake i have chosen anything ;( , so when i want to install mysql server by the command :

```
sudo apt install -f mysql-client=5.7* mysql-community-server=5.7* mysql-server=5.7*
```

they tells me :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '5.7*' for 'mysql-client' was not found
E: Unable to locate package mysql-community-server
E: Version '5.7*' for 'mysql-server' was not found
```

is there any solution please , or how to restart all the installation process from the 0

Comment: Have you Ubuntu 20.04? I think yes but unsure. Please add this info in the question. Thank you!

Comment: yes i am using 20.04